# How can I update a column with same value in another table ssms?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have 2 table --Employee Table and Emplabor Table--
Employee Table :

```
Employee Table
    EMPLOYEEID (primary key)
      ,EMPLOYEENO
      ,EMPLOYEENAME
      ,LABORCODE
      ,LOGINNAME
      ,STARTDATE
      ,ADDRESS0
```

Emplabor Table:

```
EMPLABORID (primary key)
  ,LABORCRID
  ,EMPLOYEEID
  ,LABORCODE
```

i want to update the LABORCODE column in Employee table from Emplabor
this is what i am done::

```
UPDATE dbo.EMPLOYEE
SET LABORCODE =dbo.EMPLABOR.LABORCODE
FROM dbo.EMPLABOR
WHERE dbo.EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEEID=dbo.EMPLABOR.EMPLOYEEID
```

this work is OK it was updated the LABORCODE for my all employee i was added in database, but when i am add a new employee in Employee Table and select the LABORCODE from Emplabor Table to this employee,  it dosn't found the LABORCODE in EMployee Table for that employee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Join:

```
UPDATE emp
SET LABORCODE = empl.LABORCODE
FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE emp
JOIN dbo.EMPLABOR empl
 ON emp.EMPLOYEEID =  empl.EMPLOYEEID
```